# No instala la dependencia al intentar ejecutar el comando scaffold

Tags: python, odoo

Estoy tratando de ejecutar el comando scaffold en la terminal de ubuntu, pero me manda un error en el cual dice que hay un directorio que no encuentra si ni siquiera lo tengo dentro de la ruta. No sé si configuré mal o qué tendría que hacer para que deje instalar y ejecutar ese comando.

Código del comando:

```
sudo -/odoo-bin scaffold -h
```

Comment: Hola. Parece que no le estas pasando el nombre del nuevo modulo a generar. Debería  ser `odoo scaffold nombre_de_mi_modulo`